# CMake failing to build, can't find openssl

Tags: cmake, openssl, ubuntu-18.04, cpp-netlib

I'm trying to build cpp-netlib 0.12.0 stable in Ubuntu 18.04, but when I get to running

```
$ make -j4
```

I get a lot of errors, such as:

```
error: ‘SSL_R_SHORT_READ’ was not declared in this scope
         ERR_PACK(ERR_LIB_SSL, 0, SSL_R_SHORT_READ)
```

Google told me this was because the make variables `-DOPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR` and `-DOPENSSL_SSL_LIBRARY` need to be defined. However, I can't find the directories/libraries I need to set them to. Examples give `/usr/lib/openssl-1.0` and `/usr/include/openssl-1.0`, but I can't find anything like those, even though I have the latest version of openssl installed through apt-get.

My `/usr/include` directory contains the folder 'openssl', but `usr/lib` doesn't have even that, only 'openssh', which doesn't appear to contain anything relevant.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you try with libssl-dev installed? (sudo apt install libssl-dev) Also, lack of SSL should be already reported by cmake configuration step...

Comment: I did indeed try with libssl-dev installed. Fixed this in the end by cloning the git repository and building from that instead, but later encountered a host more errors. Have now found an easier solution to what I needed to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by cloning latest version from git repository and building from that.